# How do I display all results from a query, including duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of numbers which map to names, and all I want to do is bring back everything including exact duplicates.

Data in TABLE

```
number     name
1          Tom
2          Brian
3          Steve

SELECT number, name 
FROM table
WHERE number in (1,2,1,1,3,3)
ORDER BY number
```

I'd like the output to be

```
1   Tom
2   Brian
1   Tom
1   Tom
3   Steve
3   Steve
```

but what is being returned is

```
1 Tom
2 Brian
3 Steve
```

Comment: From where you are getting this list?

Comment: The data is the table like this:

number     name
1          Tom
2          Brian
3          Steve

Comment: I meant the list you are passing in `WHERE number in (1,2,1,1,3,3)`

Comment: It's just a supplied list where they've asked for the results to be sent back as described.

Comment: How is that list supplied? As a simple string ('1,2,1,1,3,3')?

Comment: @RobertKock The OP said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707133/how-do-i-display-all-results-from-a-query-including-duplicates#comment101856763_57707226) that there can be tens of thousands of elements in the list. A `VARCHAR2` is limited to 4000 bytes which will not fit more than 2000 single digit numbers (and much fewer if they are multiple digits) so it would have to be a `CLOB` if there was a string input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it using `IN ( ... list ... )` instead you'll need to use a `JOIN` to something; for example, a collection (like the built-in `VARRAY` called `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Tom'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Brian' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Steve' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   test_data t
       INNER JOIN TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1,2,1,1,3,3 ) ) n
       ON ( t.id = n.column_value )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | NAME 
> -: | :----
>  1 | Tom  
>  2 | Brian
>  1 | Tom  
>  1 | Tom  
>  3 | Steve
>  3 | Steve
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ffceac0fe6d99bd890642b4dd36f943)*

*Note:*

[`SYS.ODCINumberList`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm#sthref955) has the type `VARRAY(32767) OF NUMBER` so can store up to 32767 numbers.

If this is not sufficient then you can define your own collection type (rather than using a `VARRAY`) like:

```sql
CREATE TYPE NumberList IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to try like below by making a table of that inside data then use join

```
with cte as
(
select 1 as id from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select 1 from dual
union all
select 1 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual
) select cte.id,t1.name from table t1 join cte on t1.number=cte.id
```

Comment: I have tens of thousands of rows though - the data I supplied was just a small sample (Sorry - should have been clearer)